# What are my options for rendering diagrams in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, diagram

I'm making a .ipynb as a tutorial for neural networks.

Sometimes I need to add diagrams.

What I'm doing currently is drawing them on paper, taking a photo with my iPhone and rendering the .png in a markdown cell with e.g. `![BackProp](backprop.png)`.

However this sucks on a few different levels. It means I have to supply a bunch of media files when distributing the notebook. Also tweaking a diagram requires from-scratch--reworking. And it looks clumsy.

I tried a couple of approaches, but couldn't get anything to work:

- It should be possible to render diagrams in LaTeX, and VSCode's .ipynb renderer handles stuff like $x^2 + y^2$. ChatGPT gave me:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm, >=stealth]
  \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4.5,0) node[right] {$x_1, x_2, \dots, x_N$};
  \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,2.5);
  \foreach \i in {1,2,...,4}
  {
    \filldraw[black] (\i,0) circle (0.1);
  }
  \draw[black, ->] (2,-0.3) -- (2,0.3);
  \draw[black, ->] (2,0.3) -- (2,1.7) node[above] {$\sum_{i=1}^{N}w_ix_i + b$};
  \draw[black, ->] (2,1.7) -- (2,2.2) node[above] {$\sigma(\cdot)$};
  \draw[->] (2,2.2) -- (4.5,2.2) node[right] {Output};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

... but this gives "ParseError: no such environment: tikzpicture" -- and it looks like I'd have to pip-install https://github.com/mkrphys/ipython-tikzmagic

- graphviz might be possible, however (1) I can't get it working with a markdown cell, and (2) even though it does work in a Python cell (after `brew install graphviz` and `pip install graphviz`),

```py
import graphviz as gv

dot = gv.Digraph()

dot.edge("X6", "X7", label="$\sigma(\cdot)$")

dot
```

... still won't render LaTeX in the diagram.

Is there *any* out-of-the-box solution that wouldn't require my students having to fiddle with installations?

And if not, is there a recommended path?

Comment: First, have you see [this](https://twitter.com/alec_helbling/status/1609037745350926336). Check out [here](https://twitter.com/alec_helbling/status/1619462340499628034) and [here](https://twitter.com/alec_helbling/status/1622286775711309825) for more about it. Or what about [Mermaid](https://github.com/knsv/mermaid)? See [here](https://bollwyvl.github.io/nb-mermaid/) for it in notebooks.

Comment: Plus [IPyDrawio](https://ipydrawio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). I'd suggest trying it from the 'launch binder' link [here](https://github.com/deathbeds/ipydrawio) as the 'Try' link on the former page is in JupyterLite and those tend to be more experimental than I like. YMMV. You'll want to look under [What can you draw with IPyDrawio](https://ipydrawio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#what-can-you-draw-with-ipydrawio). And [Features](https://github.com/deathbeds/ipydrawio#features), where it says at the bottom, "include rich LaTeX and AsciiMath typesetting in diagrams".

Comment: As for sharing... Even if you keep with your current system, you can easily share these if you start using GitHub, or another archiving system, that works in conjunction with MyBinder.org, if you'd like the notebooks to ever be active. If you just need to share things and the'll render well with nbviewer as 'static' notebooks, you can do that. For example (not in your field but should give idea), [this nbviewer view of a notebook](https://nbviewer.org/gist/fomightez/d862333d8eefb94a74a79022840680b1) has a widget that remains interactive even in 'static' view. It is actually hosted at ....

Comment: <continued> a Github site [here](https://gist.github.com/fomightez/d862333d8eefb94a74a79022840680b1) but you'll notice if you scroll to the bottom, the widget doesn't render so it is better at nbviewer. For a related but different idea, you may be interested in [MyST-NB](https://myst-nb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) [JupyterBook], related to (https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/intro.html). Or maybe [Quarto](https://quarto.org/)?